# flutter problem, The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1

Tags: flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, flutter-test

### This is my error I dont understand what is problem,
When i am building apk then i got this error.
How to fix it?

This is my error I dont understand what is problem,
When i am building apk then i got this error.
How to fix it?
This is my error I dont understand what is problem,
When i am building apk then i got this error.
How to fix it?

```
C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color build apk

 Building with sound null safety 

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_sim_country_code-0.1.2\android\src\main\java\com\example\flutter_sim_country_code\FlutterSimCountryCodePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_sign_in_android-5.2.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlesignin\GoogleSignInPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Parameter format not correct -
e: D:/Global Lancers/cwc-flutter-app/build/sign_in_with_apple/.transforms/b2c3fc047a9d7267418e111f2de6a0d1/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/sign_in_with_apple_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: D:/Global Lancers/cwc-flutter-app/build/better_player/.transforms/151bfc855fe976bf94ab40ad88e221e1/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/better_player_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: D:/Global Lancers/cwc-flutter-app/build/wakelock/.transforms/8d1905fcae49b140f3094369d4419c90/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/wakelock_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: D:/Global Lancers/cwc-flutter-app/build/audioplayers/.transforms/6631a095458426ecb5445e25a1402e45/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/audioplayers_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: D:/Global Lancers/cwc-flutter-app/build/package_info_plus/.transforms/28be655d06f4aa25e98a201585f1263b/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/package_info_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: D:/Global Lancers/cwc-flutter-app/build/fluttertoast/.transforms/afa6af91d841e4bf71a23b32c52d89d4/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/fluttertoast_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: D:/Global Lancers/cwc-flutter-app/build/stripe_android/.transforms/2bfe933eebc159364e880a45681bae73/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/stripe_android_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b3fa9517f1020cd75f3409be069b61c6/transformed/appcompat-1.5.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/appcompat_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.7.0/362da0b4951ed79a6591743a7fddcfb8c73809f6/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.7.10/1ef73fee66f45d52c67e2aca12fd945dbe0659bf/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/00867bb6132ae3ba398fbf21ecff6845/transformed/jetified-core-ktx-1.9.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9f94187b7d0d64c5f03acf766cbb58c7/transformed/core-1.9.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/403d294479ff5b9381ca5eb0849050cf/transformed/jetified-annotation-experimental-1.3.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/annotation-experimental_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.10/d2abf9e77736acc4450dc4a3f707fa2c10f5099d/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/DELL/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.10/bac80c520d0a9e3f3673bc2658c6ed02ef45a76a/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':audioplayers:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:C:\Users\DELL\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\9f94187b7d0d64c5f03acf766cbb58c7\transformed\core-1.9.0\res\values\values.xml:104:5-113:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23m 46s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                         1451.2s

┌─ Flutter Fix ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                       │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then │
│ update D:\Global Lancers\cwc-flutter-app\android\build.gradle:                               │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                      │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
```

this is my gradleBuilds->

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33


    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "org.mycwc"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

--------------------------------


  ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10' // latest version

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }
```

Comment: I think you've to change your audioplayers dependencies in pubspec.yaml and control your package with flutter version.

dependencies: audioplayers: ^1.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Updating ext.kotlin_version to latest version like suggested in all other answers wouldn't fix the error.
When I opened the project in Android studio, it proposed to update gradle and it fixed the error for me.

Now my build.gradle has those lines :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```